# Nuget Package Restore Not Working In TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

Nuget package restore is not working at all for us with TFS 2015 RC2 and a build server with Visual Studio 2015.  I have a Visual Studio Build task with "Restore Nuget Packages" checked but that step doesn't do any restore before starting the build, which then fails.  There is no error or anything that gives me a hint what would be wrong.  There is just no ouptut regarding the package restore.  I also tried adding a nuget package restore step, despite it seeming redundant but that also doesn't do anything.  No ouptut.  The build agent log looks like this:

```
23:02:49.826405 PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddCommand(C:\TFSAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.11\NuGetInstaller.ps1)
23:02:49.826405 PowerShellHandler.Execute - Add inputParameters
23:02:49.826405 PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(solution=C:\TFSAgent\_work\9c9a7daa\HiFxApi\main\src\HiFX.Api.sln)
23:02:49.826405 PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(excludeVersion=false)
23:02:49.826405 PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(noCache=false)
23:02:49.826405 PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(nuGetRestoreArgs=)
23:02:49.826405 PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(nuGetPath=)
23:02:50.074443 PowerShellHandler.Execute - Invoke

23:02:50.275946 FindFiles.FindMatchingFiles(rootFolder = , matchPattern = C:\TFSAgent\_work\9c9a7daa\HiFxApi\main\src\**\packages.config, includeFiles = True, includeFolders = False
23:02:50.275946 FindFiles.GetMatchingItems(includePatterns.Count = 1, excludePatterns.Count = 0, includeFiles = True, includeFolders = False
23:02:50.291644 FindFiles.FindMatchingFiles - Found 0 matches
23:02:50.322449 BaseLogger.LogStatus(scope.JobId = e0495eb1-3867-4bdf-8c90-196620cc0e1d, scope.TimelineRecordId = 6ac5c739-f581-4081-9cab-1404f28bfcc3, record.Name = )
23:02:50.322449 BaseLogger.LogFile(scope.JobId = e0495eb1-3867-4bdf-8c90-196620cc0e1d, path = C:\TFSAgent\_diag\w2ec95c01-f3c6-4db4-b910-0d40c922051b.log)
23:02:50.322449 JobExtensionManager.OnAfterExecuteTask
23:02:50.322449 BaseLogger.LogStatus(scope.JobId = e0495eb1-3867-4bdf-8c90-196620cc0e1d, scope.TimelineRecordId = 6ac5c739-f581-4081-9cab-1404f28bfcc3, record.Name = )
23:02:50.322449 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = e0495eb1-3867-4bdf-8c90-196620cc0e1d, message = ##[section]Finishing task: NuGetInstaller)
23:02:50.322449 LoggingEventHandlerManager.LoadLoggingEventHandlers(pluginPath=)
```

Am I supposed to have a packages.config file checked in with my solution?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you need to submit packages.config to your VCS. It contains a list of packages (+ their version & target framework) used in the solution.

`FindFiles.FindMatchingFiles - Found 0 matches` in your log hints that the build agent looked for packages.config files, found none and therefore assumed there is nothing to restore and exited without an error.

Comment: This seems completely backwards to me.  VS 2015 does not need a packages.config to do a nuget restore and it doesn't create one for you like it did in VS 2013.  If that's what's needed, that means we would have to manually maintain this packages.config as we add nuget packages to our solution.

Comment: @brushwood The only time "VS 2015 does not need packages.config" is, as far as I know, in an ASP.NET 5 project. In that case package restore needs to be done through `dnu`.

Answer (score 0):

There can be another reason of the described behavior. The `nuget restore` action, the way it is implemented in VSBuild task, searches for packages.config files underneath the solution file directory.

For example, if the solution layout resembles the one below, `nuget restore` won't find packages.config and will simply do nothing:

- Folder A

  - Folder A1
  - Folder A2

    - Folder A21
  - a.csproj
  - **a.sln**
- Folder B

  - b.csproj
  - **packages.config**

You can examine [the code of VSBuild build task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/VSBuild/VSBuild.ps1) to find out more details:

```
$slnFolder = $(Get-ItemProperty -Path $sf -Name 'DirectoryName').DirectoryName

Write-Verbose "Searching for nuget package configuration files using pattern $slnFolder\**\packages.config"
$pkgConfig = Find-Files -SearchPattern "$slnFolder\**\packages.config"
if ($pkgConfig)
{
   Write-Verbose "Running nuget package restore for $slnFolder"
   Invoke-Tool -Path $nugetPath -Arguments "restore `"$sf`" -NonInteractive" -WorkingFolder $slnFolder
}
else
{
   Write-Verbose "No nuget package configuration files found for $sf"
}
```

Comment: We do not have any packages.config files or csproj files.  The nuget dependencies are all listed in the project.json.  Visual Studio 2015 uses this file to do the nuget package restore.  Shouldn't the TFS 2015 build agent work the same way?

Comment: Of course, the build part should comply with what VS can do, but it's obviously not supported today. At least, both VSBuild and MSBuild tasks rely on packages.config to nuget restore, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I was really hoping I was just missing something and that this was supposed to work automatically ... or that there was at least some way to generate a packages.config.  Oh well, I guess I'll start manually creating some packages.config files.

Comment: Adding a packages.config doesn't actually do anything.  The old style package restore runs and downloads the nuget packages to the /packages folder but that isn't used for anything by VS 2015.