# Failure to build on VS Online because of Nuget, works locally

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

Running locally in VS2015. Everything builds fine. If I deploy to VS Online, the build fails as it cannot find HTML Agility Pack, which is in the solution as a Nuget package. I have checked that Restore NuGet Packages is ticked in VS Online.

Any thoughts on anything I'm not doing.

Comment: I've seen a similar thing before. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551294/nuget-package-restore-not-working-in-tfs-2015/31566825#31566825) for possible explanation.

Comment: That's the explanation, maybe. What's the solution? Also apply the nuget package to the first project?

Comment: The solution is to rearrange the folder layout in the repo, so that all *.csproj are placed in subfolders under *.sln level. That would make the default logic of that build task work as expected.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko, do you work with the vNext build system in VSO, or work with a XAML build definition? Please check my answer below for the details about the differences.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko that's what I do have - a folder with a .sln file and a subfolder per project, and within that folder is a packages.config file that includes a reference to HtmlAgilityPack and this all works fine in development.

Comment: @TimAlmond, then it's not your case.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I seem to have found the problem. The packages had been checked into source control. Not sure if they should or not, but there we are. By removing them from the packages folder, it then seemed to restore them from Nuget and work this time.

Answer (score 0):

If you **work with the vNext build system** in VSO, all you need to do is to check the **Restore NuGet Packages** checkbox in the build definition, and choose the .sln file you would like to build.

[image]

If you **work with one XAML build definition**, there are some steps (described [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build)) you need to follow in order to have these NuGet packages restored during the VSO (TFS) build process.

1. Add following items to the solution. (Content of the nuget.config and .tfignore file can be found [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build))

[image]

2. Add one build.proj file under the root path of the solution folder. (Content of the build.proj file can be found [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build))
3. Create one folder named **tools** under the root path of the solution folder. Create **NuGet** sub-folder under **tools** folder, download and save [nuget.exe](https://www.nuget.org/nuget.exe) under tools\NuGet path.
4. Check in **nuget.config**, **.tfignore**, **build.proj** and **tools\NuGet\nuget.exe** into TFS version control.
5. Modify the build definition to choose to build the build.proj file.
   [image]

Then you will have NuGet packages restored successfully during the TFS build process.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using vNext and have specified to restore packages, and it doesn't work.