# New Azure portal and Visual Studio Team Services continuous deployment not using NuGet

Tags: azure, msbuild, nuget, continuous-deployment, azure-devops

When I create a test solution with 2 WebForms apps and on Class Lib, check into Visual Studio Team Services, continuous deployment works and publishes to our staging slots as expected. TestSite1 and TestSite2 both build and publish on the two azure website staging deployment slots.

I accomplish the multiple websites scenario with a custom build configuration for each web app and edit each build definition like so: `Any CPU|ReleaseSite1`   for test site 1 and `Any CPU|ReleaseSite2` for test site 2.

The moment I add any NuGet library, like Newtonsoft Json then the Team Services MSBuild server fails.

This also fails for any out of the box VS2015 MVC app as the Team Services Build Server can't find System.Web.Mvc.

All this is using new Azure preview portal, Framework 4.5.2

Build

> Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find
>   more specific information about the cause of this error in above
>   messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException) Exception Stack Trace:
>   at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
>   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly
>   "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to
>   make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required
>   by your code, you may get compilation errors. default.aspx.cs (15, 0)
>   The name 'Newtonsoft' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Do the Build Definitions perform a Nuget Restore?

Comment: I don't see any setting relating to Nuget restore. There is a msbuild pre build scripts section. What would you enter there? Remember this is a cloud vso build server and not one we manage.

Comment: I thought the newer XAML builds on VSO did a Nuget Restore? Do you see it in the XAML / Diagnostic logs?

Comment: I recently answered a question about enabling Nuget Restore on TFS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565296/how-to-get-nuget-restore-in-tfs-build/33575331#33575331

Comment: Do you use the new webbased build system or the old XAML based one?

Comment: This is the default xaml but I have seen messages advertising to use new webbased build system. Should I be using that?

Comment: Thanks DaveShaw, looking at that now.

Comment: Is the Nuget package installed correctly? What is the version of the Nuget.exe installed on your PC? There is an issue with Nuget 3.1 (The version installed with VS2015) when install a Nuget package after the project has already been checked in and bound to Source Control. See this link https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1164 for details. You can installed the latest Nuget version from: http://blog.nuget.org/20150902/nuget-3.2RC.html. Then uninstall & reinstall your Nuget packages and check if the solution can be built successfully.

Comment: We tried both build systems xaml and the new. Both do the same exact thing. Identical. I develop on an azure cloud server with VS2015 Enterpise that was just installed a month ago. Nuget comes with VS2015 there have not been any customizations to those. I have tried many new projects created on other machines also and those have the same issue. Don't see how this could be environment issue.

Comment: Does the "Thanks for installing Json.NET" page display when you install Newtonsoft Json nuget package?

Answer (score 0):

The queued builds actually runs on build agent machine. You need to add NuGet package restore to the build process, so that the required NuGet packages can be downloaded during the build process.

Please check my reply in this link for the detailed steps for both vNext build system and XAML build: [Failure to build on VS Online because of Nuget, works locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591217/failure-to-build-on-vs-online-because-of-nuget-works-locally)